# account not accessible through brownie accounts while using --network ganache-local

Tags: web3.py, brownie

```
(eth-brownie) PS C:\Users\lucky\Desktop\Investing\Courses\Solidity\demos\brownie_fund_me> brownie run scripts/deploy.py --network ganache-local
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.18.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieFundMeProject is the active project.

Running '\Users\lucky\Desktop\Investing\Courses\Solidity\demos\brownie_fund_me\scripts\deploy.py::main'...
File "C:\Users\lucky.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie_cli\run.py", line 51, in main
return_value, frame = run(
File "C:\Users\lucky.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 103, in run
return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
File "\Users\lucky\Desktop\Investing\Courses\Solidity\demos\brownie_fund_me\scripts\deploy.py", line 31, in main
deploy_fund_me()
File "\Users\lucky\Desktop\Investing\Courses\Solidity\demos\brownie_fund_me\scripts\deploy.py", line 10, in deploy_fund_me
account = get_account()
File ".\scripts\helpful_scripts.py", line 12, in get_account
return accounts[0]
File "C:\Users\lucky.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py", line 115, in getitem
return self._accounts[key]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I can run the chain locally and on the rinkeby testnet, but when I run it using --network ganache-local, it is throwing this error. I think it is not able to get the account address.

Answer (score 0):

When you have ganache running in the background, brownie will tell you which host it is using to connect. This can be found if you run `brownie run scripts/deploy.py`

Mine ended up seeing host 127.0.0.1 instead of the host that I used for my ganache-local network.

To change the host for your network, try `brownie networks modify ganache-local host=http://127.0.0.1:8545`

Comment: I set the `host=http://0.0.0.0:8545` as I had configured ganache that way but it wasn't working. But when I configured `host=http://127.0.0.1:8545` it worked. I think we need to specify ganache, the exact IP and port number for it to function as you rightly mentioned. Thanks for the help.